# Sort Select Options using JQuery

Tags: jquery

The following works for a single `select` in a page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.quantity option').sort(function (a, b) {
    var optValA = parseFloat( $(a).attr('value'));
    var optValB = parseFloat( $(b).attr('value'));
    return (optValA < optValB) ? -1 : (optValA > optValB) ? 1 : 0;
  }).appendTo('.quantity');
});
```

I have 2 or more `select` in a page. I also want retain the `selected` option.

Comment: please share your html for which you are applying sort functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to sort multiple of them you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quantity').each(function() {
    $('option', this).sort(function(a, b) {
      var optValA = parseFloat($(a).attr('value'));
      var optValB = parseFloat($(b).attr('value'));
      return (optValA < optValB) ? -1 : (optValA > optValB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quantity').each(function() {
    $('option', this).sort(function(a, b) {
      var optValA = parseFloat($(a).attr('value'));
      var optValB = parseFloat($(b).attr('value'));
      return (optValA < optValB) ? -1 : (optValA > optValB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="quantity">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select class="quantity">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select class="quantity">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

I made a function where you pass the select

You can then sort one at a time or sort all

It turns out you will not lose the selected value

```js
function sortSel($sel) {
  // const selectedValue = $sel.val(); // not actually needed
  $('option', $sel).sort(function(a, b) {
    var optValA = parseFloat($(a).attr('value'));
    var optValB = parseFloat($(b).attr('value'));
    return (optValA < optValB) ? -1 : (optValA > optValB) ? 1 : 0;
  }).appendTo($sel);
  // $sel.val(selectedValue); // not needed 
}

// sortSel($(".sel1")); // one at a time
// sortSel($(".sel2"));

$("select").each(function() {
  sortSel($(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel1">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="0.3" selected>C</option>
  <option value="0.1">A</option>
  <option value="0.2">B</option>
</select>

<select class="sel2">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1.3" selected>C</option>
  <option value="1.1">A</option>
  <option value="1.2">B</option>
</select>
```